# Trace back output in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, output

Programming in Python in Visual Studio Code, I was wondering if there exists a way, given an output, to trace back to the respective input. If, for example, a print is generated by a line in my code, does there exist a command, or a tool of VS Code, such that I can find exactly the line where this output was produced? Maybe it's a trivial question, but it would be useful for me if someone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, you can use a function breakpoint() .

```
def foo():
    a = input()
    breakpoint() #Put it and debug interface will be opened in terminal
    generated_result = a + 'abc'
    return generated_result
```